# pyOpenGL GLUT window function doesn't close properly

Tags: python, opengl, glut, pyopengl, freeglut

This minimum working example of an environment with PyOpenGl and GLUT presents the same issue I am having on bigger code. Creating/closing continuously an instance of this class, increases memory usage until all my machine starts slowing down.

What is happening is that the call to `glutDestroyWindow` has not effect and the process `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg` quickly fills up the whole GPU.

```
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 2000, 2000

class TestEnv:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = None
        glutInit(sys.argv)
        glutInitWindowSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT)
        self.window = glutCreateWindow(b"TestEnv")

    def close(self):
        if self.window:
            glutDestroyWindow(self.window)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    i = 0
    while True:
        env = TestEnv()
        env.close()
        print(i)
        i+=1
```

What is the correct way of releasing all resources?

Comment: I don't use glut, but it looks like you are freeing the window instance, but not the memory occupied by `glutInit(sys.argv)`? Maybe surf the glut docs from some kind of glutDone()?

Answer (score 0):

[PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) uses [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/). You have to give *freeglut* the chance to close the window. `glutDestroyWindow` does not destroy the window immediately, but triggers an event that destroys the window. There for you have to run the event loop. Invoke [`glutMainLoopEvent`](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php#EventProcessing) after requesting the window to be destroyed:

```py
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 2000, 2000

class TestEnv:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = None
        glutInit(sys.argv)
        glutInitWindowSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT)
        self.window = glutCreateWindow(b"TestEnv")

    def close(self):
        if self.window:
            glutDestroyWindow(self.window)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    i = 0
    while True:
        env = TestEnv()
        env.close()
        glutMainLoopEvent() # <--- handle events
        print(i)
        i += 1
```

See also [Immediate mode and legacy OpenGL](https://github.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/blob/master/readme/content_python_legacy.md)